# session.merge() not working as expected in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have just learned about session.merge() in Java and wanted to use in my project. I am querying for a user, and based on the result I receive, either create a new user or update the existing one like this. With `user` being an entity created beforehand to update the existing user record. I am facing trouble in updating the user.

```
User QueryUser = (User) session.createQuery(xxx);

org.hibernate.Transaction tx = null;

if (QueryUser == null) {
    System.out.println("Creating New User!!!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Updating User!!!");
    long userId = QueryUser.getId();
    user.setId(userId);
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(user);
    tx.commit();
}
```

From what I've learned, merge updates persisted entity with data from transient entity provided both of them have same identifiers. So, here `user` entity should be updated with fields from `QueryUser` entity, but it is not happening. Can someone please help me find the issue or explain a better way to do it?